# Recursive function returning undefined value

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch the object from multi level structure

I written function for it but even on return its not coming out from function and returning value, its continue with next recursion. I know its returning value to the previously called function and as its scope is block its getting overridden and that's why returning undefined value

```
  var selectedObj = findObjectByUid( existingStructure, selectedUid);
function findObjectByUid( root, selectedUid ) {
    if( root.uniqueId === selectedUid ) {
        return root;
    }
    if( root.children && root.children.length > 0 ) {
        for( var k in root.children ) {
            if( root.children[ k ].uniqueId === selectedUid ) {
                return root.children[ k ];
            } else if( root.children.length ) {
                return findObjectByUid( root.children[ k ], selectedUid );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i want to get back to my initial calling function when it got matching uid.

Comment: Can you add a sample JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you return with the first child, regardless of the found node.

You could take a temporary variable and store the result of the children check and if not falsy return this value.

BTW, you could take the child directly of the array for the recursion.

```
function findObjectByUid(root, selectedUid) {
    if (root.uniqueId === selectedUid) return root;
    if (!root.children || !root.children.length) return;
    for (let child of root.children) {
        let temp = findObjectByUid(child, selectedUid);
        if (temp) return temp;
    }
}

var selectedObj = findObjectByUid(existingStructure, selectedUid);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with using this approach on arrays. First, the for...in also iterates over an object's prototype properties if those properties are enumerable. For example:

```
Array.prototype.voice = "James Earl Jones";

var tMinus = [
  "Two",
  "One",
  "Blast off!"
];

var countdown = "";

for (var step in tMinus) {
  countdown += tMinus[step] + "\n";
}

console.log(countdown);
// => "Two
//    One
//    Blast Off!
//    James Earl Jones
//    "
```

That can be solved by using hasOwnProperty to exclude prototype properties.
Example:

```
for (var step in tMinus) {
  if (tMinus.hasOwnProperty(step)) {
    countdown += tMinus[step] + "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: or use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are corrected code. You had used `return findObjectByUid` in inner calling by which code was terminating before completing loop.

```
function findObjectByUid( root, selectedUid ,foundArr) {

  if( root.uniqueId === selectedUid ) {
    foundArr.push(root);
      return root;
  }
  else if( root.children && root.children.length > 0 ) {
      for( var k in root.children ) {
           findObjectByUid( root.children[k], selectedUid,foundArr ); 
          if(root.children[k]=== selectedUid){break;}
      }
  }
   return foundArr.length>0?foundArr[0]:null;
}
```

Sample json and calling method

```
var root = {uniqueId:1,children:[{uniqueId:10},{uniqueId:11,children:[{uniqueId:21,children:[]},{uniqueId:22,children:[]},{uniqueId:23,children:[{uniqueId:31,children:[]},{uniqueId:32,children:[]}]}]},{uniqueId:12,children:[]},{uniqueId:13,children:[]}]};
findObjectByUid(root,32,[]);
```